# Apt-get seems to be broken. Cannot install anything

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

How can I fix this?

```
rimmer@local:/$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-24 linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You might need to delete some old kernels to free up space. Please post the output of `uname -r` as well as `dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)`

Comment: It looks like a kernel is broken:  `Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic)`.  Is there another kernel installed on your system so that you can purge 4.4.0-28?  After all 4.4.0-31 is out and you don't need 28 anyway.